# ¿como hacer update desde un boton tomando los datos de un DataGridView?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Buen dia.

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Quiero hacer un Update en una tabla de SQL (InventarioLab) dando click en el boton **Tomar** cuando se seleccione una fila en DataGridView.  El Update quiero se realize en la columna **Status**.
Por el momento no tengo ningun codigo.

Esta es la interfaz:

[image: Interfaz]

ESpero me puedan ayudar

Comment: -Define el primer metodo listartabla();
-en una variable guardas la columna de la fila dgv.currentrow[i].columns["columna"].tostring();
----------------------------------------------------
como obtienes el valor de la columna .......(evento click+dgv.currentrow[iD].columns["columna"].tostring)
---------------------------------------------------
AL PRESIONAR EL BOTON EJECUTA TODO EL ALGORITMO Y AL ULTIMO EL LISTAR TABLA PARA QUE SE REFRESQUE O ALGO POR AHI VA LA IDEA...(AYUDEN CON LA PUBLICACION DEL IIS T,.T)

Comment: Sería buena idea agregar lo que has intentado por ejemplo al dar click como trataste de actualizar?

Comment: @Jorgesys no tengo nada. y no tengo idea de como hacerlo. es primera vez que lo estoy intentando

Answer (score 1):

Realize lo siguente y me funciono correctamente:

```
Private Sub btnTomar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTomar.Click
    Try
        txtIDTemporal.Text = dgvTecnicos.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
        txtNuevoStatus.Text = "Fuera de Laboratorio"
        Dim con As String
        con = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=LabInventarioN3;User ID=f5;Password=f5report"
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = con
        Dim query As New SqlCommand("update InventarioLab set Status = '" & txtNuevoStatus.Text & "' where ID = " & txtIDTemporal.Text & "", cn)
        cn.Open()
        query.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Se Actualizaron los datos")

        Dim dts As New datos
        Dim funciones As New funcion
        dts.gusuario = My.Forms.IniciodeSecion.UsernameTextBox.Text
        dts.gcontraseña = My.Forms.IniciodeSecion.PasswordTextBox.Text
        dts.gproyecto = Proyecto()

        If funciones.validar(dts) = True And Proyecto() = 1 Then 'El 1 es de Cambium
            obj.MostrarDatosCambium(dgvTecnicos)
        Else
            If funciones.validar(dts) = True And Proyecto() = 2 Then 'El 2 es de Enphase
                obj.MostrarDatosEnphase(dgvTecnicos)
            Else
                If funciones.validar(dts) = True And Proyecto() = 3 Then 'El 3 es de Estructurales
                    obj.MostrarDatosEstructurales(dgvTecnicos)
                Else
                    If funciones.validar(dts) = True And Proyecto() = 4 Then ' El 4 es de ICT
                        obj.MostrarDatosICT(dgvTecnicos)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error al Actualizar Datos : " + ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```